# How to create pivot table for two users (teachers, students) accessing the same Course table as asiggned to and enrolled to using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an issue in creating the database structure to be supported by laravel on the above subject.
The structure of my tables is this.

**Users Table:**

- Name
- Type
- Email
- Password

**Course**

- Name
- Description

I am using a single users table to authenticate both teachers and students whenever they log in to the system. The column "Type" is used to define the user type i.e. admin, teacher and student.

Now the issue comes. The system requirements are:

***Requirements***

- Course lists showing the assigned teachers on the course
- Teachers are assigned the courses by admins
- Teachers enroll the students to their class
- Students will see their courses after being enrolled showing the course teacher too.

How can I build a pivot table for this scenario in laravel, because according to my idea this is what I have in mind.

**course_user**

- course_id
- user_id

But am failing how to identify that this course is assigned to this teacher, and this teacher has enrolled this student to this particular course using the same pivot table.

Please help enlighten me up.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two relation functions with additional filer like this:

```php
class Course extends Model
{
...
    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where('type', '=', User::TEACHER);
    }

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where('type', '=', User::STUDENT);
    }
}
```

I assume that you use class constants in User class.

Comment: Does this mean i can use a many to many scenario in my usecase?